# Puppeteer question: How to loop thorough an elementhandle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a function that extracts textContent from a CSS or XPath selector.

Can someone help me to achieve this? I'm confused

```html
const nodes = await page.$$('css selector here');
for (const node of nodes) {
    const stuff = await extractText(page, node, 'css selector to extract text') || null;
}
```

so it will extract text only if the node has the specified selector, otherwise output as null.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question needs details and clarity -- real websites work in many different, complex ways thanks to arbitrary JS behavior and DOM structures, so there's no one-size-fits-all solution. Please share the actual site you're working with, and actual, runnable code instead of pseudocode as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can try something like this:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <p>Text 1.</p>
      <p>Text <span>2</span>.</p>
    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${encodeURIComponent(html)}`);

  const nodes = await page.$$('p');
  for (const node of nodes) {
    const stuff = await extractText(page, node, 'span') || null;
    console.log(stuff);
  }
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }

function extractText(page, node, selector) {
  return page.evaluate(
    (node, selector) => node.querySelector(selector)?.innerText ?? null,
    node,
    selector,
  );
}
```

Comment: You did understand right, but It returns wrong values. Let's say for example i have a list of div boxes with classname "box" and i want to loop thorough all boxes and get their "selector text" such as a title only if the div box title selector exists, otherwise return null, but i need to check for each individual div with "box" classname to see if they have a selector which i need to return the text from

Comment: @CookieMonsta' Does the new variant of the answer returns right values?

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: @CookieMonsta' Cay you add to the question the URL or the HTML example and the required output?

Comment: Thanks you everyone for the help! <3 I marked as solved because @vsemozhebuty solution works!

Comment: When I replied that it doesn't work for some reason I didn't copy the right version of the code. It works thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Sample HTML:

```
 <ul>
 <!-- Nodes you would like to be evaluated -->
 <li class="red">Color Red 1</li> <!-- Node you would like not to extractText and get null as result -->
 <li class="red">Color Red 2</li> <!-- Node you would like not to extractText and get null as result -->
 <li class="blue">Color Blue 1</li> <!-- Node you would like to extractText -->
 <li class="blue">Color Blue 2</li> <!-- Node you would like to extractText -->
 <!-- Nodes you would not like to be evaluated -->
 <li class="green">Color Green 1</li>
 <li class="green">Color Green 2</li>
 <li class="yellow">Color Yellow 1</li>
 <li class="yellow">Color Yellow 2</li>
 </ul>
```

Puppeteer code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const extractText = async (page, node, selector) => {
    // In complex scenarios use nodeClassName will not be enough 
    // and you will need to use the Private API of ElementHandle _remoteObject
   
const nodeClassName = await node.getProperty('className')
const nodeJsonValue = await nodeClassName.jsonValue()
const nodeValueForComparison = '.' + nodeJsonValue

if(nodeValueForComparison === selector){  
    const text = await page.$eval(selector, element => element.innerText)
    console.log(text)
    return text
}

    return null
}

 (async() => {
    const url = 'Your URL'  
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false}); 
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('url');
    // Pass the selectors of Nodes you would like to be evaluated
    // separated by a comma
    const nodes = await page.$$('.red, .blue', node => node);
    const result = [];
    for (const node of nodes) {
        const stuff = await extractText(page, node, '.blue');
        result.push(stuff)
    }
    console.log(result)
    await browser.close();
})();
```

[image: It is working right for me]

Comment: Thanks for helping but what you posted doesn't really work

Comment: I made some changes, try it now.

To use the Private API _remoteObject use also the element in the selector

const nodes = await page.$$('li.red, li.blue', node => node);

Comment: Thanks for replying, I ran your code again and returns all null :z

Comment: Try on a real website :)